# Comparing lists with custom conditions

Tags: list, prolog

So the teacher did a version in class that I did not understand and he didn't upload it. I was hoping someone could show me how they'd do it and walk me through the logic. The question is as follows

> Write a Prolog function that takes three parameters: two input lists and an output variable that is equal to 0 if the length of the first list is less than that of the second list, and becomes 2 if the length of the first list is greater than that of the second list. If the lengths of the two lists are equal, then if the sum of all numbers in the first list is less than or equal to that of the second list, the output value equals 1. Otherwise, the output value becomes 4.

In the end the function when called on should be doing something like

```
?-output([15,3.5,5.5],[1.0,2.0], Y).
Y=2

Yes
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all?

Comment: I've tried to get started, but everything I write just ends up looking wrong so I erase it. Figured after about 10 minutes of doing that, it'd be better to ask for help.

Comment: Only 10 minutes? You won't learn much only spending 10 minutes on a problem. Start by studying some of Prolog's list processing ability. Google search "prolog lists" for example. Get familiar with the language features available.

Comment: Alright I'll check that out, thank you! But yeah I mean with the previous questions I've been able to at least get something started and play around with that. With this one I wasn't making any headway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are many ways to accomplish this in Prolog, you will likely end up with a four-clause rule, with one clause dedicated to each of the outputs that you are looking to produce:

```
output(A, B, 0) :- ...
output(A, B, 2) :- ...
output(A, B, 1) :- ...
output(A, B, 4) :- ...
```

The `...` represent the logical conditions that trigger the desired output expressed in Prolog syntax. For example, to write "length of A is less than length of B" in Prolog you would write this:

```
output(A, B, 0) :- length(A, LA), length(B, LB), LA < LB.
```

This means "Get length of `A` into `LA`, and get length of `B` into `LB`. Length of `A` must be less than length of `B` in order for the rule to succeed."

You can use unification to write the condition "`A` and `B` have the same length" without introducing two additional variables:

```
length(A, L), length(B, L), ...
```

This means "Both `A` and `B` have the same length `L`."

Use [`sum_list/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sum_list/2) instead of [`length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=length/2) to get the sum of the list.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed, I should be able to build off of here, thanks

Comment: Am I understanding the syntax correctly, that when I get to the "otherwise" part of the question (where I output 4 in every other case not met by the other conditions) that I would just write output(A, B, 4) : - ; or is it something else?

Comment: @butimnotarapper The proper syntax for that would be `output(A, B, 4).` However, it wouldn't work in your case unless you put a cut `!` in the remaining three branches: without a cut, asking for more results after a query would bring `4` for situations with other answers, which is wrong. Long story short, you need a complete condition for the "otherwise" part as well.